# #1305 FUNCTION dbname.json_arrayagg does not exist

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.7

maybe I miss something. But why do this function doesn't exist?

Based on the documentation it should be:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Version: 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Somebody help me out pls :) This function could help me out well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON_ARRAYAGG was introduced in MySQL 5.7.22.

If you have a space between a function name and the parentheses (`JSON_OBJECTAGG ("item", item.item_id)`). MySQL, by default, [does not handle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) the function name as a built-in function.

You can either remove the space between then function name and the parentheses or use sql_mode `IGNORE_SPACE`. Easier just not to use the space.

Comment: Damn, where it was written? Honestly I thought about that, but I could not find it.

Comment: "Added in MySQL 5.7.22." in the very page you linked ;)

Comment: I am on `5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-log` and I can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` but I can not use `JSON_OBJECTAGG`. it says "JSON_OBJECTAGG does not exist". Any Idea?

Comment: @hriziya  How are you using it?

Comment: I am using like this only https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg

Comment: @hriziya How does you code look like when you use it?

Comment: I am executing it in phpmyadmin directly to test my queries

Comment: Can you show what the "it" looks like? Unfortunately I cannot tell what your phpmyadmin query looks like if you do not show it.

Comment: ```SELECT  est.estimate_id
, JSON_OBJECTAGG ("item", item.item_id) 
FROM tbl_estimates est 
LEFT JOIN tbl_estimate_items item ON est.estimate_id = item.estimate_id
WHERE est.estimate_id = 3
GROUP BY est.estimate_id
 ```
This is my query.

Comment: Remove the space between the function name and the parentheses i.e. use `JSON_OBJECTAGG("item", item.item_id)`. In order to make MySQL ignore the space, you would have to use sql_mode `IGNORE_SPACE`. Easier just not to use the space.

Comment: @slaakso you should write that as an answer.

Comment: i cant believe it was that simple! removing the space (why was it even in there!!) in my query worked. this after furiously reading up on percona documentation and getting really upset cause its supposed to work... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My work-around solution.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(category_id, accuracy)), '(},{)', ',')
```

Seems in Mariadb 10.5 this function is active.

Comment: My work-around solution.
REGEXP_REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(category_id, accuracy)), '(},{)', ',')

Seems in Mariadb 10.5 this function is active.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, update your MariaDB manually to 10.5.0

**BE CAREFUL ABOUT YOUR DATA!**

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/

JSON_OBJECTAGG MariaDB starting with 10.5.0

JSON_OBJECTAGG was added in MariaDB 10.5.0.

Comment: I'd appreciate you provide us a detailed instruction how to update MariaDB 10.4 to 10.5.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428841/how-to-update-mariadb-from-10-4-to-10-5-under-xampp-win10

Answer (score 0):

You can use different functions with same approach

```
 // 1-  DB::raw(" JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_extract(title)) AS test")

 // 2-  DB::raw(" CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_EXTRACT(title)), ']')  AS test")

 // 3-  DB::raw(" GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(title)))  AS test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this technique for JSON objects

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("{status:'",status,"'"), CONCAT("case-count:'",cnt,"'"), CONCAT("}") ) ,"]") as data
FROM ....
```